# How do i make many to many field as a chekbox items in template.?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 models one is Category(Fields = category_name) and another one is SubSategory(Fields = category(ForeignKey to Category),sub_category).and another model is DummyModel.

```
# Model
class DummyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    sub_category = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory)
```

This is my form

```
class StartProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StartProject
        fields = (
            'name',
            'email',
            'category',
            'sub_category',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StartProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["category"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["category"].queryset = Category.objects.all()

        self.fields["sub_category"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["sub_category"].queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        clean = self.cleaned_data.get
        name = clean('name')
        email = clean('email')
        category = clean('category')
        sub_category = clean('sub_category')

        obj = StartProject()
        obj.name = name
        obj.email = email
        obj.category = category
        obj.sub_category = sub_category
        obj.save()
```

This is my view

```
#view

class StartProjectView(View):
    template_name = 'start-project.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = StartProjectForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = StartProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = StartProjectForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

        return HttpResponse("<h2>Done</h2>")
```

This is my Template

```
# Template

<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
        {% for form in form %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="category">{{ form.category }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        {% for form in form %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub_category">{{ form.sub_category }}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Start Now</button>
    </form>
```

I want category and subcategory in my template as checkbox items. How do I do that.?

Comment: You should add your StartProjectForm code as well, thx.

Comment: I added the form

Comment: Did you tried to show the form fully rendered using {{ form }}? what it shows?

Your {% for form in form %} statements are not correct, maybe you want to use {% for field in form.visible_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}

Comment: yes I tried the form method {{ form }} it's working. but I want to make a custom form using HTML in the template

Comment: Ok, using {{ form.FIELD_NAME }} should do the trick. Take a look at the docs -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

or maybe consider using some package like django-crispy-forms which allows you to fully customize your forms.

Comment: **{% for field in form.visible_fields %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}** this code is working same as **{{ form }}**
This is not what I really wanted.

Comment: Take a look at my previous comment :)

Comment: ok let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in your needs, what you are looking for is `{{ form.FIELD_NAME }}`.

Whit your form `{{ form.category }}` and `{{ form.sub_category }}` should work.

Take into account that this only renders the input itself, nor labels or other DOM elements.

Review the docs on 'Rendering fields manually' for more info -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually